# AndroidTV - create custom layout

Tags: android, android-tv

I checked android docs, but didn't really find an answer on how to show custom layout in my application. I'm thinking of custom fragment placed next to navigation drawer. Maybe someone can give me pseudo code for better understanding? Thanks.

Visual representation:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rNAU.jpg

On specific itemClick I want to make a layout (that contains icons/pictures) and place it next to nav drawer.

Answer (score 0):

The key-word you are searching for is resource buckets. Essentially you can create resource-folders based on screen size, API version, orientation and such. Refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on how to create layouts for different screen sizes.
In Android Studio you can create resource-files based on those quantifiers by open the "new resource file" dialog and selecting the quantifiers you want in the lower part of the dialog.
Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html) to read on layouts made exclusively for TVs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my post, so it's easier to understand what I want to accomplish. I think you might not understand my question exactly or I did not understand your answer/tips. I think that correct way would be to make a fragment (which extends god knows what?) and is placed next to nav drawer as overlay fragment. Is it possible?